# Extracting characters from even index position

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract only charters from even index position. For example I trying to do this with this strings below:

```
s = 'Michael Jordan'
for k in range(len(s)):
  if k%2==1:
    print(s[k])
```

But unfortunately this code give me only values odd not for even index position, so can anybody help me how to solve this ? Output should be horizontal like example below

```
'M''c''a''l'J''r'a'
```

Comment: range starts in 0,1,2,....

Comment: Do you mean `print(*s[::2])`?

Comment: Did you think to try `if k % 2 == 1:`?

Comment: Have you considered replacing `==1` by `==0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking with if is redundant here since range itself has `step`. Just do it in this way:

```
s = 'Michael Jordan'
for k in range(0, len(s), 2): # 2 here is the step
    print(s[k])
```